# How to manage connection string in c# applications

Tags: c#, .net

How to manage `connectionstring` in c# application.Is it a good practise to `encrypt` the string within the database connection class in the project ?

```
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + strServer + ";AttachDbFilename=" + path + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=120;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: There are couple existing questions on storing secrets in .Net applications (or applications in general). I'd recommend searching and possibly finding solution that way....

Comment: constr should be inside app settings or web.config file